# PHP exec/passthru adds environment variables

Tags: php, shell, environment-variables

I'm running php-fpm with `clear_env = yes` (the default).

And indeed

```
echo getenv('PATH');
```

outputs nothing.

However,

```
passthru('set');
```

outputs:

> ```
> HOME='/'
> HOSTNAME='pod-ed3f8236c1-g3ksb'
> IFS='     
> '
> LINENO=''
> OPTIND='1'
> PATH='/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin'
> PPID='203'
> PS1='\w \$ '
> PS2='> '
> PS4='+ '
> PWD='/app/www'
> SHLVL='1'
> USER='nobody'
> ```

Where do those environment variables come from?

I put my actual problem into [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171314/xelatex-fails-unless-i-re-set-path-to-what-it-already-is). I was hoping this question would help me understand what is going on there.

Comment: Those are coming from the OS. `passthru` is running the `set` command, which according to it's man page, `Set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters.` When you run `set` on the command line, that's what you'd get

Comment: You are running an OS command, those come from the OS. php-fpm cannot clear the OS environment vars.

Comment: I put my actual problem into [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171314/xelatex-fails-unless-i-re-set-path-to-what-it-already-is). I was hoping this question would help me understand what is going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set aside, for the moment, the involvement of PHP in your question. Open a terminal window; i.e., an interactive shell. Type `env` to display all the exported, that is environment, variables. now type `env -i env` to run the same command with an empty environment. The first `env` should show all the expected env vars; e.g., `PATH` and `HOME`. The second should output nothin showing that the `env -i` has in fact removed all env vars. Now type `env -i bash -c set`. Whoa! What are all those vars and where did they come from?

Part of the answer is that the shell's `set` command does not show just env vars. It shows all the vars defined in the shell's execution context. Now do `env -i bash -c env`. That will show just the env vars created by the shell. Notice the list is much shorter. In particular note that `bash -c set` listed vars like `PATH` but the `bash -c env` does not. That's because while the shell defined a default PATH so that it would be minimally functional it did not automatically export that var.

When you execute `passthru('set');` you're more or less doing the same thing as typing `bash -c set` at a shell prompt. And that doesn't just show env vars. I said "more or less" because in reality php is probably doing `sh -c set` "under the hood" and the behavior of sh will differ subtly from other shells like bash, ksh, or zsh.